# VSCode Python's extension does not automatically activate virtual environment in Remote Development Extension over WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

Update: here's [the bug I filed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/368) with specific instruction of how to replicate, although I'm not sure if it's a bug.

I'm using VSCode Insiders' [Remote Development Extension over WSL](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/05/02/remote-development).

VSCode's Python extension *does* recognize the virtual environment and it works as expected when debugging.

But, when I open a new integrated terminal the virtual environment is not automatically activated.

When I was working natively on Windows, the venv was activated automatically.

Of course, I could activate manually each time, but the automatic activation is very handy.

Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5553 does this help your problem?

Comment: This is an old question. I guess it was resolved, because lately my virtual environment is automatically activated. I'm not sure what the problem was.